# IBM Language Translator returns 403 Forbidden upon identify()

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I followed the official documentation to create a multilingual Watson assistant outlined here:
https://github.com/with-watson/multilingual-chatbot

However, after deploying the function on IBM Cloud and testing the deployed function via IBM Cloud CLI with the below command, I am getting an error (logs below):

> bx wsk action invoke translator --result --param text "Hallo, ich habe eine Frage."

{
    "error": "The action did not return a dictionary."
}

```
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787506Z    stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787554Z    stderr: File \"pythonrunner.py\", line 88, in run",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787560Z    stderr: exec('fun = %s(param)' % self.mainFn, self.global_context)",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787564Z    stderr: File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787568Z    stderr: File \"__main__.py\", line 98, in main",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787571Z    stderr: response = translator.identify( text )",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787575Z    stderr: File \"/action/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/language_translator_v3.py\", line 193, in identify",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787579Z    stderr: accept_json=True)",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787583Z    stderr: File \"/action/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/watson_developer_cloud/watson_service.py\", line 587, in request",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787587Z    stderr: info=error_info, httpResponse=response)",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.787591Z    stderr: watson_developer_cloud.watson_service.WatsonApiException: Error: Forbidden, Code: 403",
"2020-01-13T12:54:57.788Z       stderr: The action did not initialize or run as expected. Log data might be missing."
```

Looks like the API key is recognized but not permitted to be used for this action, however the key being used does return the right values when used via cURL.

The code executed in main is the same as provided on the Github above, I did not make any changes.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What are you passing in place of workspace_id in the params.json file?

Comment: I'm passing the Skill ID grabbed from Skills > View API Details > Skill ID

Comment: I just tried running the code sample and everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

The key string used by curl is a bearer token.  The API key needed by the cloud function is probably one provided by Identity and Access Management, IAM.

In the https://cloud.ibm.com console GUI in the top click Manage > Access (IAM) then select the IBM Cloud API keys on the left and select an API key.  This creates an API key that represents you, just like login name and credentials.  This is the simplest way to get this to work, but is not great for production.

For production consider using a Service ID and probably in combination with Access Group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested your suggestion but I'm still getting 403 after swapping the key to an IBM Cloud API key. Also, previously I have created Service IDs along with API keys for both resources (Assistant, Language Translate) as recommended by their guide - result is the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me with additional changes

I have run the below command to update the packages mentioned in the `environment.yml` file

```
conda update --all
```

- The conda version on my machine is `4.8.1`
- cloud-functions/wsk/functions/fn plugin version is 1.0.36

Comment: I updated the packages as per your suggestion and have the same conda and cloud functions version, but it did not help unfortunately. However, I recreated the resources (Translator, Assistant) in another region (changed to us-south - prev. eu-gb) and it started to work immediately.

Answer (score -1):

While creating Language Translator instance make sure to choose the right region.
It worked for me after I changed it.